# App::abort(404) equivalent for Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, http-status-code-404

In `Laravel 4` i used to be able to simply call

```
App::abort(404)
```

Is there an equivalent in `Laravel 5`?

There seems to be surprisingly limited information out there about this at the time of writing. I've found discussions on how to *[catch NotFoundHttpExceptions](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-register-a-custom-404-in-laravel-5?page=1)* but that isn't what I want, as the url structure is already processed by my *routes.php* file. To give some more background, here's a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

**Routes.php:**

```
Route::get('/info/{page}', array('as' => 'info', 'uses' => 'Primary@infoPage'));
```

**Primary.php (controller)**

```
public function infoPage($page){
    $pageData = DB::table('pages')->where('url_title', $page)->first();
    if(!empty($pageData)){
       // great, there's a corresponding row in the database for this page, go ahead and do stuff...
    }else {
       // This page doesn't exist, please abort with a 404 error... but how?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38):

You just have to look at the [Official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#http-exceptions).

### HTTP Exceptions

Some exceptions describe HTTP error codes from the server. For example, this may be a "page not found" error (404), an "unauthorized error" (401) or even a developer generated 500 error. In order to return such a response, use the following:

```
abort(404);
```

Optionally, you may provide a response:

```
abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
```

This method may be used at any time during the request's lifecycle.

### Custom 404 Error Page

To return a custom view for all 404 errors, create a `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` file. This view will be served on all 404 errors generated by your application.

### Update

Seems that this function has been removed and will soon be replaced as written [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-404). A "workaround" can be creating a 404 response.

#### Creating Custom Responses

For most routes and controller actions, you will be returning a full `Illuminate\Http\Response` instance or a view. Returning a full `Response` instance allows you to customize the response's HTTP status code and headers. A `Response` instance inherits from the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` class, providing a variety of methods for building HTTP responses:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

return (new Response($content, $status))
    ->header('Content-Type', $value);
```

For convenience, you may also use the response helper:

```
return response($content, $status)
    ->header('Content-Type', $value);
```

**Note**: For a full list of available Response methods, check out its [API documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Response.html) and the [Symfony API documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html).

Comment: I tried that and get NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 879: ... wait, is that what I *should* get?

Comment: I'd also read this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-404 and understood that such a method didn't exist

Comment: @Ingo If you use `abort(404)`, `NotFoundHttpException` will be thrown.